# Deploy .NET Framework 3.5 via GPO

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, windows-10, gpo

I am trying to create a GPO to deploy the .NET Framework 3.5 on all workstations in a specific group. I've written a Powershell script that when run manually installs .NET Framework 3.5 successfully. However when run via a GPO (Either as a Computer or User policy) .NET  3.5 is never installed to the workstation.

My script,

```
$dotNet35Key = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5"

if (-Not (Test-Path $dotNet35Key)) {
    & Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName NetFX3 –All -Online -NoRestart -Source "\\TECH\OS_Images\Win10Prox64\sources\sxs" -LimitAccess
}
```

I've reviewed the [MS documentation for .NET Framework 3.5 being being deployed via GPO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/deploy-net-framework-35-by-using-group-policy-feature-on-demand-setting), but in my testing that policy only allows for manually enabling the .NET Framework 3.5 as an optional feature.

Any thoughts or suggestions on how to force the .NET Framework 3.5 to be installed on all workstations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's not going to work on workstations.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Right, hence the post - Any advice on an alternate method?